# Probably, expected eatings on a roulette wheel

Tags: probability, statistics

The probability that a roulette wheel stops on a red number is $\frac{18}{37}$

For each bet on “red” you are returned twice your bet (including your bet) if the wheel stops on a red number, and lose your money if it does not.

(a) If you bet 1 dollar on each of 10 consecutive plays, what is your expected winnings? What is your expected winnings if you bet 10 dollars on a single play?

(b) For each of the two cases in part (a), calculate the probability that you made a profit (that is, your “winnings” are positive, not negative).

I'm a bit confused on setting up the formula to solve this question.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: What's the definition of expected value E[X]?

Comment: I believe it is:

$$E(x)=\sum xf(x)$$

for all values of x

Comment: Awesome. Clarify what $x$ and $f(x)$ mean with respect to your problem, and then apply accordingly.

Comment: How would I determine what $f(x)$ is though?

Comment: Also what are the values for $x$?

Comment: Do you know what a binomial distribution is?

Comment: ^ Yes, does that apply here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(a)(i)$ Let random variable $X$ be the total winnings over $10$ rolls.

Let $X_i$, for $i=1,\ldots,10$, be the winnings for the $i^{th}$ roll. So, $X=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{10}{X_i}$.

Then for any $i$,
\begin{eqnarray*}
E(X_i) &=& 1\cdot P(\text{$i^{th}$ roll is red}) - 1\cdot P(\text{$i^{th}$ roll is not red}) \\
&=& \dfrac{18}{37} - \dfrac{19}{37} \\
&=& -\dfrac{1}{37}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Then,

\begin{eqnarray*}
E(X) &=& E\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{10}{X_i}\right) \\
&=& \sum\limits_{i=1}^{10}{E(X_i)} \qquad\text{(by linearity of expectation)} \\
&=& 10 \cdot \left(-\dfrac{1}{37}\right) \\
&=& -\dfrac{10}{37}.
\end{eqnarray*}

$(a)(ii)$ If $X$ is the winnings from the single \$$10$ bet, then,

\begin{eqnarray*}
E(X) &=& 10\cdot P(\text{the roll is red}) - 10\cdot P(\text{the roll is not red}) \\
&=& 10\cdot \dfrac{18}{37} - 10\cdot \dfrac{19}{37} \\
&=& -\dfrac{10}{37}.
\end{eqnarray*}

$(b)(i)$ With $10$ bets, to make a profit you need to win at least $6$ of them. Thus,

\begin{eqnarray*}
P(\text{Profit}) &=& P(\text{at least $6$ reds}) \\
&=& \sum\limits_{i=6}^{10}{\binom{10}{i} \left(\dfrac{18}{37}\right)^i \left(\dfrac{19}{37}\right)^{10-i}} \qquad\text{(using Binomial distribution)} \\
&=& 0.344165 \qquad\text{(by actual calculation)}
\end{eqnarray*}

$(b)(ii)$ With a single bet you obviously have to win it to make a profit. Thus,

\begin{eqnarray*}
P(\text{Profit}) &=& P(\text{the roll is red}) \\
&=& \dfrac{18}{37}.\end{eqnarray*}